# Problem faced to get multiple images from client to server and there is problem with foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here I give a view of HTML code, PHP Code and Error after run the code.
I also use print_r($_FILES) to check data of array but it show me an empty array.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div>
    <label>Upload Multiple Images</label>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="product_image" name="product_image[]" multiple="true" required="true" />
    </div>
</div>

<div>   
    <button type="submit" name="product_submit" id="product_submit" value="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

    include("connection.php");

    foreach ($_FILES["product_image"] as $key => $value) 
    {
        $filename = $_FILES["product_image"][$value]["name"];
        echo $filename;
    }

    print_r($_FILES);
<?>
```

**ERROR**

```
Notice: Undefined index: product_image in C:\xampp\htdocs\...
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\..
Array ( )
```

Comment: From the code you provided it's not clear how you send data to your backend.
Please take a look at  this topics: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/tour and 2. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your array `$_FILES` does not have `product_image` index in it, means if you are submitting data from client, it is not coming to server.